# Damped Iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

For splitting $A = M-P$ a damped iteration with damping factor $\gamma <1$ and scalar $\omega$ is $$x^{k+1} = x^{k} +\gamma M^{-1}r^{k}$$
where $$r^{k} = b-Ax^{k}$$ $$M =\frac{1}{\omega }I $$ $$P = \frac{1}{\omega }I - A$$
Show that if $M^{-1}A$ has real, postive eigenvalues, then the damped iteration associated with $M$ converges for sufficiently small $\gamma$.  Use this to show show damped Jacobi converges

Comment: Hi Doe, can you give us a little bit of context about this problem, for example how you got interested? Also, tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Its just a problem from the textbook _Fundamentals of Matrix Computation_.  I haven't tried anything I don't know how to start the problem and this is the problem verbatim so its all the context I have

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: $\omega$ is a scalar

Comment: If you plug the definition of $r$ into the first equation, you see that your method is a fixed point iteration with the iteration function $F(x)=(I-\gamma M^{-1}A)x+\gamma M^{-1} b$. What do you know about convergence of fixed point iteration?